# Execute a background task when I turn my PC on - Windows Store App

Tags: c#, windows, windows-store-apps, background-task

My app is running on a tablet having Windows 8.1 Pro.

I got lock screen access calling this:

```
  await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();
```

A time trigger run my background task with these conditions (Internet and UserPresent):

```
         // adding condition
         SystemCondition internetCondition = new SystemCondition(SystemConditionType.InternetAvailable);
         SystemCondition userPresentCondition = new SystemCondition(SystemConditionType.UserPresent); 

         builder.AddCondition(internetCondition);
         builder.AddCondition(userPresentCondition);
         BackgroundTaskRegistration taskRegistration = builder.Register();
```

it works properly but when I turn off my device, it does not start again.

Which condition shall I add (if it is possible)?

Same question on [msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/620cec0d-a1e9-49f4-bd4d-a54f6ebee24e/how-to-execute-a-background-task-when-i-turn-my-pc-on-windows-store-app?forum=wpdevelop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for future usage, I fixed it adding another background task with a system trigger with session condition.